# Normed bounded sequence of $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere

I was working for my final exam in analysis from Aliprantis and Burkinshaw's *Principles of Real Analysis*. I got stuck at this problem. Any help is appreciated.

If $\{f_n\}$ is a norm bounded sequence of $L^2[0,1]$, then show that $\dfrac{f_n}{n} \overset{\text{a.e.}}{\longrightarrow}0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{2}}\leq C<\infty$ for each $n$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int\sum_{n}\dfrac{|f_{n}(x)|^{2}}{n^{2}}dx&=\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\int|f_{n}(x)|^{2}dx\\ \ \\ &\leq C^{2}\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}\dfrac{|f_{n}(x)|^{2}}{n^{2}}<\infty~~~~\text{a.e.}
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f_{n}(x)}{n^{2}}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
for all such $x$.